# How to save the JSON data in User-Defaults

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to save the `JSON` data in `user-defaults` but I am getting an error like

> "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

at line `defaults_userlogindetails.synchronize()`.

```
 var username = NSString()
 username = userdetails.value(forKey: "name") as! NSString
 print(username)
 let defaults_username = UserDefaults.standard
 defaults_username.set(userdetails, forKey: "userdetailsname-login")
 defaults_username.synchronize()
 defaults_username.object(forKey: "userdetailsname-login")
 print(defaults_username)
```

Comment: Please don't use `NSString` or any `NS` thing in `Swift`. Also you should not initialise `String` object like this.

Comment: Please don't save json data in user defaults.

Comment: Even don't call `defaults_username.synchronize()` method too.

Comment: how to save the data??

Comment: save json to a json file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if your json object parameter nil so you can not store because null is not primitive types so it can not store in user default

Comment: It should be in comment section.

Comment: 1. `nil` is not of any type, it represents null pointer 2. There's nothing wrong with setting `nil` in user defaults, it's a functional equivalent of `removeObject(forKey:)` 3. Signature of `set(_:forKey:)` clearly shows that it accepts an optional value